# No exiting CPE in the official CPE dictionary

Tags: execve

In some CVE, we can read some **CPE** like :

cpe:/a:libcap:libcap:2.00

cpe:/a:gnome:libsoup:2.32.2

cpe:/a:libgtop:libgtop:2.14.5

But neither libcap nor libsoup nor libgtop are in the **official CPE dictionary** !!

(XML file or online search : https://nvd.nist.gov/cpe.cfm)

How can it be possible ?

Thank you,
Florent

Comment: What can we do to help you on this question? Do you mean you need somebody to figure out why these libs are not in the official CPE dictionary??

Comment: I need to understand why these CPE, which exist in the CVE details, don't exist in the official CPE dictionary.